# View в Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, frontend

Здравствуйте, уважаемые коллеги! Осваиваю Spring MVC уверенными шагами, но есть один вопрос на который не могу найти внятного ответа. 
В данный момент я тружусь на web-приложением, используя Spring MVC. С back-end всё прозрачно и понятно, а вот с front-end неразбериха. 
На "фронте" я хочу использовать Java Script, а вернее React JS. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли это? Рационально ли это? И если да, куда копать, чтобы это реализовать? А если нет, то как быть?
P.S: хочу максимально уйти от JSP+JSTL

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Rest

Comment: Виктор, спасибо. А можно чуть подробнее?

Comment: [вики REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)